# React router dom don't render pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my page don't render the HomePage
but if i only use

h1 Test HomePage h1

in render it work.

i wanna know where i should fix it or what im doing wrong
thanks for help

or you need to see the other file you can tell me

im kinda new to the programming

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HomePage/>
      </div>

    );

  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

this is my HomePage Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <p>This is the home page</p>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/join" component={RoomJoinPage} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateRoomPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the React code. Are there any console errors? What is the installed version of `react-router-dom`? From the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom` and report the installed version.

Comment: @DrewReese react-router-dom@6.3.0 invalid: "^5.2.0" from the root project

Comment: Version 6.2.2 is the current `react-router-dom` version. Seems you might have conflicting versions in your app.